# PHP-SPX - Seeing profiling results made by CLI command on the web GUI

Tags: php, profiler

We want to see the speeds of services written in PHP, so we decided to use PHP-SPX (https://github.com/NoiseByNorthwest/php-spx)

To try it out, we got a simple script with a while(true) loop and we added spx_profiler_start() and spx_profiler_stop() within the loop. Between these method calls, there's my echo command to output something.

The CLI command is the following: SPX_ENABLED=1 SPX_REPORT=full SPX_AUTO_START=0 php testScript.php

The web GUI itself is working nicely when it comes to track the website calls via webbrowser, which is on the same server where we are using the CLI command. We can click on the entries seen in the results table, also all the graphs, etc. But we cannot see any entries involving the CLI calls and its results.

Are there maybe any setting we did not consider yet?

Comment: Does both CLI and web reports appear in data dir (`/tmp/spx` by default)? What are file permissions there, and can webserver / fpm process read them?

Comment: @weirdan the /tmp/spx contains files generated by CLI only. I got no clue where the web-based information are stored. And yet it must read those information from somewhere. Folder spx got 775.

Comment: Then it's worth checking `php.ini` settings in both environments: `<?php phpinfo` for web and `php -i` for CLI. See if they have `spx.data_dir` set to different values.

If they differ, you found the cause. If they don't, check whether web profiles can be found in folder named like `/tmp/systemd-private-*`. If latter is the case, change `spx.data_dir` to a folder *outside* `/tmp`.